Checkbox on gridcell is not checkable using playwright Ts
I need to assert the status of this checkbox (as checked/unchecked) (arrowed in picture).
checkbox in grid cell
Code (in rectangle) is reproduced below:
<div column="0" class="webix_column  webix_first webix_select_mark" style="" xpath="1">
   <div role="gridcell" aria-rowindex="1" aria-colindex="1" class="webix_cell" style="" tabindex="0">
       <span class="webix_table_checkbox webix_icon wxi-checkbox-marked">
       </span>
   </div>
</div>

To check the status, I asserted thus:
const mapBox = page.locator("//span[@class='webix_table_checkbox webix_icon wxi-checkbox-marked']").nth(0);
await mapBox.isChecked();
//OR 
// await expect(mapBox).toBeChecked();

...but either way, I got thrown:
Error: locator.isChecked: Error: Not a checkbox or radio button
Call log:
  - waiting for locator('//span[@class=\'webix_table_checkbox webix_icon wxi-checkbox-marked\']').first()

It turns out the selector is an {object} type as:
console.log("Map box: ", typeof mapBox);
...gives:
Map box:  object 
For sure, there is a way to ascertain the checkbox's status, I just need someone to point it out. Thank you.

await mapBox.isChecked(); is a no-op on its own line, not an assertion. Your locator and expect look fine, though, so probably more context (a [mcve] with the actual site and full code) will be needed to debug this. Is the element in an iframe, or is the page blocking you, or is there an element preventing visibility/actionability?

@ggorlen It is a proprietary site, so it is not accessible to public. There is no shadow-dom or iframe involved. Thanks

Oh yeah, looking closer at the error, you're trying to check a <span>, so the error message is pretty self-explanatory (hopefully). It may be a <span> styled like a checkbox, but isn't actually one. So try asserting on some other indication of whether it's checked.
